# Bootstrap 4.5 - Collapse not working, jQuery and all CDN packages installed

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm getting into bootstrap for the first time and to do that I've copied some code from one of their demo pages onto my own site as a test, the code for the nav bar is from the offical bootstrap examples:

```
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/carousel/
```

In this demo when the browser is at its minimum width you can toggle the 'hamburger' menu to hide and show the nav links and search bar.

This does not work for me, clicking the menu button does nothing. I can tell that the CSS is definitely installed because the css styles are working, and when I check my code the scripts also all appear so it doesn't appear to be a lack of jQuery (my initial thought).

```
<header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarCollapse" style="">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
```

I am also enqueing all scripts from my Wordpress `.function.php` file as follows:

```
function wpbootstrap_enqueue_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'boot1','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'boot2','https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'boot3','https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ),'',true );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpbootstrap_enqueue_styles');
```

Edit: it is definitely an issue with how my scripts are being called. If I post the scripts directly into the page the collapse is working, I can't see any problems with the enque though, and when I search the code the scripts are there. Is it an issue with ordering?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem due to JS or Jquery script file. I had the same issues. I used different script files. It solved my issues.

For CSS, use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

For scripts use these:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Hope this helps you as well!